# Is scipy supported in C ? or how can we use scipy in pycuda

Tags: python, scipy, gpu

Actually i'm using scipy library methods "solve" and "lstsq" in my python algorithm. I Need to use this method in pycuda (i.e) for executing in GPU.
Is scipy supported in C ? or how can we use scipy in pycuda.

Please help me get some solution on this?

Comment: Take a look at lapack or so. I'm sure there's a graphics card equivalent

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given a look at a library called `cupy`?

Then you can have a look at https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.linalg.lstsq.html

and
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.linalg.solve.html